# Java Set of Maps hashCode incorrect?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode

I am getting unexpected results from a Set of Maps (`Set<Map<String,String>>`), where `s.contains(s.iterator().next())` is `false`.

The set in question contains only one map that is `[{=262.666666666666667}]` (the empty String mapped to the String `262.666666666666667`).

I have been unable to put together a minimal working example that replicates the problem as the following outputs true:

```
Set s = new HashSet<Map<String,String>>();
Map<String,String> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put("", "262.666666666666667");
s.add(m);
System.out.println(s.contains(s.iterator().next()));
```

HashMap does not override hashCode but Abstract map does (see below) so I don't see the problem of putting a HashMap in a HashSet.

```
public int hashCode()
{
     int h = 0;
     Iterator<Entry<K,V>> i = entrySet().iterator();
     while (i.hasNext())
         h += i.next().hashCode();
     return h;
}
```

What is the  reason for this behaviour and how can I fix it?

Edit: Thanks at doublep and morgano, I indeed modified the map after adding it and resolved the issue by adding after the modification instead of before.

Comment: Multiple threads? Until we've got *something* which reproduces the problem, it's hard to help...

Comment: Your self-contained example returns `true` when executed on a single thread.

Comment: What do you mean by unexpected results?

Comment: Perhaps some rounding issue?

Comment: @JonSkeet: There is only a single thread. I will try to reproduce it.

Comment: @Mena: Exactly that is stated in my post.

Comment: @KonradHöffner sorry, I read it too fast. I suggest adding some context to make it possible to reproduce.

Comment: If you modify a member map *after* adding it to the set, and thus changing map's hashcode, set will become broken. That's the reason Python, for example, requires that dictionary keys are immutable.

Comment: @doublep: Exactly that was the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to reproduce the error, modify your code in this way:

```
    Set s = new HashSet<Map<String,String>>();
    Map<String,String> m = new HashMap<>();
    s.add(m);
    m.put("", "262.666666666666667");
    System.out.println(s.contains(s.iterator().next()));
```

That is, add the map to the set and then put a new key/value in the map.

The problem is that, as you said, Abstract map overrides `equals()` to depend on the key/values that the map holds at that moment. Set uses internally a Map, being the key the value of `equals()` at the moment your Map is being added to the set. When you add a new key/value to your Map then the value returned by `equals()` also changes and doesn't correspond to the original value, this way you get false for `System.out.println(s.contains(s.iterator().next()));`